# Is there any pattern/algorithm to know number of some property in dynamic tree?

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, tree

I have a dynamic tree - nodes can be added/removed anytime. Every node:

- can have N children;
- has array of `foo`;
- can add/remove `foo` to/from to his own `foo` array.

And I always need to know how many total `foo` in tree. Is there any pattern or algorithm for such problem, taking into consideration there is always only one thread (no multithreading)?

Comment: If you can store this value in a large scope variable (file scope, global scope ...), that could be done in constant time. Since there is no multi threading, it seems like a reasonable solution.

Comment: Keep a record of the number and update the value with each delete / insert / change.

Answer (score 0):

A link/cut tree can provide O(log n) time operations regardless of the tree depth. The implementations I know of don't parallelize well though.